# QT5.0 Cross compile for AM1808 ARM9

Tags: arm, cross-platform, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, qt5

I have a requirement to implement the JSON for file transfer.

I found that QJsonDocument is only supported to the QT5.0.

So that I am trying to Cross compile the QT5.0 for my processor(AM1808 ARM9).
I am using UBUNTU v12.10.

I am using arm-none-gnueabi-gcc toolchain to cross compile it.

I have tried to cross compile it using the following configure command.

```
./configure -prefix /home/ -release -make libs -xplatform mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -confirm-license -opensource -no-xcb -make examples -verbose
```

I am  getting an error like following:

```
<<srcbase> = /opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtbase 
<outbase> = /opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtbase 
Creating qmake...
make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
Running configuration tests...
Warning: Disabling pkg-config since PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR is not set.
Warning: Disabling pkg-config since PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR is not set.
Determining architecture... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o arch.o arch.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++  -o arch arch.o    
{ test -n "" && DESTDIR="" || DESTDIR=.; } && test $(gdb --version | sed -e 's,[^0-9]\+\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\).*,\1\2,;q') -gt 72 && gdb --nx --batch --quiet -ex 'set confirm off' -ex "save gdb-index $DESTDIR" -ex quit 'arch' && test -f arch.gdb-index && arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objcopy --add-section '.gdb_index=arch.gdb-index' --set-section-flags '.gdb_index=readonly' 'arch' 'arch' && rm -f arch.gdb-index || true
    Found architecture in binary
CFG_ARCH="arm"
CFG_CPUFEATURES=""
Determining architecture... ()
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -o arch.o arch.cpp
g++  -o arch arch.o    
{ test -n "" && DESTDIR="" || DESTDIR=.; } && test $(gdb --version | sed -e 's,[^0-9]\+\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\).*,\1\2,;q') -gt 72 && gdb --nx --batch --quiet -ex 'set confirm off' -ex "save gdb-index $DESTDIR" -ex quit 'arch' && test -f arch.gdb-index && objcopy --add-section '.gdb_index=arch.gdb-index' --set-section-flags '.gdb_index=readonly' 'arch' 'arch' && rm -f arch.gdb-index || true
    Found architecture in binary
CFG_HOST_ARCH="i386"
CFG_HOST_CPUFEATURES=""
System architecture: 'arm'
Host architecture: 'i386'
C++11 auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o c++11.o c++11.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o c++11 c++11.o    
C++11 enabled.
floatmath auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o floatmath.o floatmath.cpp
floatmath.cpp:44:5: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
floatmath.cpp:44:5: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o floatmath floatmath.o    
floatmath enabled.
sse2 auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -msse2 -g -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o sse2.o sse2.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option '-msse2'
make: *** [sse2.o] Error 1
sse2 disabled.
sse3 auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -msse3 -g -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o sse3.o sse3.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option '-msse3'
make: *** [sse3.o] Error 1
sse3 disabled.
ssse3 auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -mssse3 -g -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o ssse3.o ssse3.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option '-mssse3'
make: *** [ssse3.o] Error 1
ssse3 disabled.
sse4_1 auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -msse4.1 -g -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o sse4_1.o sse4_1.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option '-msse4.1'
make: *** [sse4_1.o] Error 1
sse4_1 disabled.
sse4_2 auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -msse4.2 -g -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o sse4_2.o sse4_2.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option '-msse4.2'
make: *** [sse4_2.o] Error 1
sse4_2 disabled.
avx auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -mavx -g -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o avx.o avx.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option '-mavx'
make: *** [avx.o] Error 1
avx disabled.
neon auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -mfpu=neon -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o neon.o neon.cpp
In file included from neon.cpp:42:0:
/opt/arm-2012.03/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/include/arm_neon.h:32:2: error: #error You must enable NEON instructions (e.g. -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon) to use arm_neon.h
neon.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
neon.cpp:46:5: error: 'int32x4_t' was not declared in this scope
neon.cpp:46:15: error: expected ';' before 'null'
neon.cpp:49:29: error: 'null' was not declared in this scope
neon.cpp:49:36: error: 'vst1q_lane_s32' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [neon.o] Error 1
neon disabled.
zlib auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o zlib.o zlib.cpp
zlib.cpp:42:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [zlib.o] Error 1
zlib disabled.
libjpeg auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o libjpeg.o libjpeg.cpp
libjpeg.cpp:45:21: fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [libjpeg.o] Error 1
libjpeg disabled.
libpng auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o libpng.o libpng.cpp
libpng.cpp:42:17: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [libpng.o] Error 1
libpng disabled.
DB2 auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o db2.o db2.cpp
db2.cpp:42:20: fatal error: sqlcli.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [db2.o] Error 1
DB2 disabled.
InterBase auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o ibase.o ibase.cpp
ibase.cpp:42:19: fatal error: ibase.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [ibase.o] Error 1
InterBase disabled.
MySQL (thread-safe) auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o mysql.o ../mysql/mysql.cpp
../mysql/mysql.cpp:42:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mysql.o] Error 1
MySQL (thread-safe) disabled.
MySQL (thread-unsafe) auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o mysql.o mysql.cpp
mysql.cpp:42:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mysql.o] Error 1
MySQL (thread-unsafe) disabled.
OCI auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o oci.o oci.cpp
oci.cpp:42:17: fatal error: oci.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [oci.o] Error 1
OCI disabled.
ODBC auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o odbc.o odbc.cpp
odbc.cpp:45:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [odbc.o] Error 1
ODBC disabled.
iODBC auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o iodbc.o iodbc.cpp
iodbc.cpp:42:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [iodbc.o] Error 1
iODBC disabled.
PostgreSQL auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o psql.o psql.cpp
psql.cpp:42:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [psql.o] Error 1
PostgreSQL disabled.
SQLite2 auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o sqlite2.o sqlite2.cpp
sqlite2.cpp:42:20: fatal error: sqlite.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [sqlite2.o] Error 1
SQLite2 disabled.
TDS auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o tds.o tds.cpp
tds.cpp:42:22: fatal error: sybfront.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [tds.o] Error 1
TDS disabled.
NIS auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o nis.o nis.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o nis nis.o   -lnsl 
NIS enabled.
Cups auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o cups.o cups.cpp
cups.cpp:42:23: fatal error: cups/cups.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [cups.o] Error 1
Cups disabled.
POSIX iconv auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o iconv.o iconv.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o iconv iconv.o    
POSIX iconv enabled.
D-Bus auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o dbus.o dbus.cpp
dbus.cpp:43:23: fatal error: dbus/dbus.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [dbus.o] Error 1
D-Bus disabled.
Glib auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o glib.o glib.cpp
glib.cpp:44:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [glib.o] Error 1
Glib disabled.
ICU auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o icu.o icu.cpp
icu.cpp:42:28: fatal error: unicode/utypes.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [icu.o] Error 1
ICU disabled.
PulseAudio auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o pulseaudio.o pulseaudio.cpp
pulseaudio.cpp:42:30: fatal error: pulse/pulseaudio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [pulseaudio.o] Error 1
PulseAudio disabled.
OpenGL auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o opengldesktop.o opengldesktop.cpp
opengldesktop.cpp:45:19: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [opengldesktop.o] Error 1
OpenGL disabled.
OpenGL ES 2.x auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o opengles2.o opengles2.cpp
opengles2.cpp:45:25: fatal error: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [opengles2.o] Error 1
OpenGL ES 2.x disabled.
FontConfig auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o fontconfig.o fontconfig.cpp
fontconfig.cpp:42:22: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [fontconfig.o] Error 1
FontConfig disabled.
libudev auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o libudev.o libudev.cpp
libudev.cpp:42:21: fatal error: libudev.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [libudev.o] Error 1
libudev disabled.
evdev auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o evdev.o evdev.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o evdev evdev.o    
evdev enabled.
XLib auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o xlib.o xlib.cpp
xlib.cpp:42:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [xlib.o] Error 1
XLib disabled.
Xrender auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o xrender.o xrender.cpp
xrender.cpp:42:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [xrender.o] Error 1
Xrender disabled.
LinuxFB auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o linuxfb.o linuxfb.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o linuxfb linuxfb.o    
LinuxFB enabled.
KMS auto-detection... ()
Project ERROR: Package libdrm not found
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
KMS disabled.
EGL auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o egl.o egl.cpp
egl.cpp:42:21: fatal error: EGL/egl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [egl.o] Error 1
EGL disabled.
FreeType auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o freetype.o freetype.cpp
freetype.cpp:42:22: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [freetype.o] Error 1
FreeType disabled.
STL auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o stltest.o stltest.cpp
stltest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
stltest.cpp:136:13: warning: variable 'first' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
stltest.cpp:138:16: warning: variable 'second' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
stltest.cpp:109:9: warning: variable 'v1size' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
stltest.cpp:111:9: warning: variable 'v1capacity' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
stltest.cpp:115:10: warning: variable 'v1notfound' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
stltest.cpp:119:10: warning: variable 'v1found' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
stltest.cpp:124:9: warning: variable 'v2size' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
stltest.cpp:132:9: warning: variable 'm1size' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
stltest.cpp:142:9: warning: variable 'm2size' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
stltest.cpp:146:9: warning: unused variable 'n' [-Wunused-variable]
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o stl stltest.o    
STL enabled.
POSIX clock_gettime() auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o clock-gettime.o clock-gettime.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o clock-gettime clock-gettime.o    -lrt
POSIX clock_gettime() enabled.
POSIX Monotonic Clock auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o clock-monotonic.o clock-monotonic.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o clock-monotonic clock-monotonic.o    -lrt
POSIX Monotonic Clock enabled.
mremap auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o mremap.o mremap.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o mremap mremap.o    
mremap enabled.
getaddrinfo auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o getaddrinfotest.o getaddrinfotest.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o getaddrinfo getaddrinfotest.o    
getaddrinfo enabled.
inotify auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o inotifytest.o inotifytest.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o inotify inotifytest.o    
inotify enabled.
IPv6 interface name auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o ipv6ifname.o ipv6ifname.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o ipv6ifname ipv6ifname.o    
IPv6 interface name enabled.
getifaddrs auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o getifaddrs.o getifaddrs.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o getifaddrs getifaddrs.o    
getifaddrs enabled.
OpenSSL auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o openssl.o openssl.cpp
openssl.cpp:42:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [openssl.o] Error 1
OpenSSL disabled.
PCRE auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o pcre.o pcre.cpp
pcre.cpp:42:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [pcre.o] Error 1
PCRE disabled.
OpenVG auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o openvg.o openvg.cpp
openvg.cpp:48:23: fatal error: VG/openvg.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [openvg.o] Error 1
OpenVG disabled.
OpenVG auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o openvg.o openvg.cpp
openvg.cpp:48:23: fatal error: VG/openvg.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [openvg.o] Error 1
OpenVG disabled.
OpenVG (lc includes) auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_LOWER_CASE_VG_INCLUDES -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o openvg.o openvg.cpp
openvg.cpp:46:23: fatal error: vg/openvg.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [openvg.o] Error 1
OpenVG (lc includes) disabled.
OpenVG (lc includes) auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_LOWER_CASE_VG_INCLUDES -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o openvg.o openvg.cpp
openvg.cpp:46:23: fatal error: vg/openvg.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [openvg.o] Error 1
OpenVG (lc includes) disabled.
alsa auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o alsatest.o alsatest.cpp
alsatest.cpp:42:28: fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [alsatest.o] Error 1
alsa disabled.
javascriptcore-jit auto-detection... ()
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o hwcap_test.o hwcap_test.cpp
hwcap_test.cpp:43:5: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
hwcap_test.cpp:43:5: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o javascriptcore-jit hwcap_test.o    
javascriptcore-jit enabled.
Testing size of pointers ... (/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ yes /opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtbase /opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtbase)
rm -f ptrsizetest.o
rm -f *~ core *.core
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -I. -o ptrsizetest.o ptrsizetest.cpp
ptrsizetest.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
ptrsizetest.cpp:59:12: error: 'PointerSize' is not a member of 'QPointerSizeTest<4>'
make: *** [ptrsizetest.o] Error 1
Pointer size: 4

Building on:   linux-g++
Building for:  linux-arm-gnueabi-g++
Architecture:  arm, features:
Host architecture: i386, features:
Platform notes:

            - Also available for Linux: linux-kcc linux-icc linux-cxx

qmake vars .......... styles += mac fusion windows DEFINES += QT_NO_LIBUDEV DEFINES += QT_NO_XCB PRECOMPILED_DIR = .pch/release-shared OBJECTS_DIR = .obj/release-shared MOC_DIR = .moc/release-shared RCC_DIR = .rcc/release-shared UI_DIR = .uic/release-shared sql-drivers =  sql-plugins =  sqlite qmake switches ......... 
Build ..................  libs examples
Configuration ..........  cross_compile qpa largefile precompile_header pcre  minimal-config small-config medium-config large-config full-config no-pkg-config evdev linuxfb c++11 accessibility shared qpa reduce_exports reduce_relocations clock-gettime clock-monotonic mremap getaddrinfo ipv6ifname getifaddrs inotify png freetype zlib nis iconv rpath concurrent audio-backend v8 v8snapshot release
Debug .................. no
C++11 support .......... yes
pkg-config ............. no
Qt D-Bus module ........ no
Qt Concurrent code ..... yes
Qt GUI module .......... yes
Qt Widgets module ...... yes
JavaScriptCore JIT ..... To be decided by JavaScriptCore
QML debugging .......... yes
PCH support ............ yes
iWMMXt support ......... no
NEON support ........... no
IPv6 ifname support .... yes
getaddrinfo support .... yes
getifaddrs support ..... yes
Accessibility .......... yes
NIS support ............ yes
CUPS support ........... no
Iconv support .......... yes
Glib support ........... no
GStreamer support ...... no
PulseAudio support ..... no
Large File support ..... yes
GIF support ............ plugin
JPEG support ........... plugin (qt)
PNG support ............ yes (qt)
zlib support ........... yes
Session management ..... auto
libudev support ........ no
Use system proxies ..... no
OpenGL support ......... no
OpenVG support ......... no
XShape support ......... auto
XVideo support ......... auto
XSync support .......... auto
Xinerama support ....... runtime
Xcursor support ........ runtime
Xfixes support ......... runtime
Xrandr support ......... runtime
Xi support ............. runtime
Xi2 support ............ auto
MIT-SHM support ........ auto
FontConfig support ..... no
XKB Support ............ auto
GTK theme support ...... no
SQLite support ......... plugin (qt)
OpenSSL support ........ no 
Alsa support ........... no
libICU support ......... no
PCRE support ........... qt
Xcb support ............ no
Xrender support ........ no
EGLFS support .......... no
DirectFB support ....... no
LinuxFB support ........ yes
KMS support ............ no

Could not find qmake configuration file mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++.>
```

I have changed the ***qmake.conf*** file as per according to my requirement.

I am not able to cross compile it.

Please help.

Comment: Recently i had to cross-compile Qt for ARM as well. The following worked perfectly for me - `./configure -embedded arm -platform qws/linux-x86-g++ -xplatform qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -depths 16,24,32 -no-mmx -no-3dnow -no-sse -no-sse2 -no-glib -no-cups -no-largefile -no-accessibility -no-openssl -no-gtkstyle -qt-mouse-pc -qt-mouse-linuxtp -qt-mouse-linuxinput -plugin-mouse-linuxtp -plugin-mouse-pc -fast -no-pch`

Comment: I think you have cross compiled qt which is lower then v5.0.2 as qws directory is not available in QT5.0. instead of it mkspecs is available.

Comment: Yes. You are right it was Qt4.8. :-/ I guess you would need to figure out the `mkspecs` equivalent of the above command then.

Comment: Seems easy. You might want to take a look at [**this**](http://gpupowered.org/node/8), [**this**](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27076) and [**this**](http://tigraphics.blogspot.tw/). :-)

Comment: yes you are right but for that i need to switch to the new toolchain of linaro. am I right ?

Comment: I am NOT sure you really **must** switch to the newer toolchain. But it would be better if you do switch to the toolchain that is proven to work.

Comment: yes that why.. i want to cross compile it using arm-none-gnueabi toolchain

Comment: This might helpful http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.it/2013/03/bring-up-qt-501-on-raspberry-pi-with.html

Comment: Thank you but I need to cross compile it for gcc-none-gnueabi-g++.it is not there i dont know which toolchain is using for raspberry pi board.

Comment: I have cross Compiled using the LINARO toolchain but it failed.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `-xplatform mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++` to `-xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++`.